# fit function in gnuplot at x-log(y) scale

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

My data has two columns: date (in Month/Year format) and corresponding value. I plotted this data on x-log(y) scale using gnuplot. It looks very close to a straight line. I am interested to draw a straight line using curve fitting. I tried with few fit functions but did not get success.

I tried the following fit functions:

- f(x) = a * x + b  (f(x) is not linear as scale is x-log(y))
- f(x) = a*10**x + b (overflow error)

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The overflow error should be due to at least one large value of x.  If you can rescale the x data so that there is no overflow when calculating 10**x, the fit might work.  As a test, try something like:

x_scaled = x / 1000.0

f(x_scaled) = a*10**x_scaled + b

Inspecting the maximum value of x will give you an idea of the scaling value, shown as 1000.0 in my example.

Comment: I have x data in month/year format such as 06/1995. I tried to find a fit function with a*10**(b*x/(365*24*3600) +c) and it worked. Thank you for your help.